# for loop confusion while creating the object..output is not as expected

Tags: java, collections

I have the below logic which returns HashMap with errorCode as key and `List<OrderStatus>` as value.

```
private Map<Integer, List<OrderStatus>> customCodeOrders(List<BulkAmendment> bulkAmendment) {
        Integer VALIDATION_FAILURE_STATUS = 10;
        Integer ORDER_BY_MSGNO = 20;
        Map<Integer, List<OrderStatus>> integerListFinalMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<OrderStatus> oderRefErrorList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (BulkAmendment bulkAmendment : bulkAmendment) {
            List<OrderStatus> ordRefs = bulkAmendment.getOrderStatuss();
            for (OrderStatus ordRef : ordRefs) {
                if (ordRef.getErrorBooleanCondition()) {
                    oderRefErrorList.add(ordRef);
                    integerListFinalMap.put(VALIDATION_FAILURE_STATUS, oderRefErrorList);
                } else {
                    try {
                        if (ordRef.getErrorBooleanCondition()) {
                            oderRefErrorList.add(ordRef);
                            integerListFinalMap.put(0, oderRefErrorList);
                        } else {
                            oderRefErrorList.add(ordRef);
                            integerListFinalMap.put(ORDER_BY_MSGNO, oderRefErrorList);
                        }
                    } catch (OrderException orderError) {
                        int errorNo = 145;
                        if (orderError.getMessage() != null) {
                            errorNo = 152;
                        }
                        oderRefErrorList.add(ordRef);
                        integerListFinalMap.put(errorNo, oderRefErrorList);
                    }
                }
                //  integerListFinalMap.put(1,oderRefErrorList);
            }
        }
        return integerListFinalMap;
    }
```

The output of the above code is it is storing and returning the same value for all the keys(errorCode).

```
20:[OrderReference(dealerCode=PAX1001, vin=1001, errorBooleanCondition=true), OrderReference(dealerCode=PAX1002, vin=1002, errorBooleanCondition=false), OrderReference(dealerCode=PAX1003, vin=1003, errorBooleanCondition=false), OrderReference(dealerCode=DC2001, vin=2001, errorBooleanCondition=true), OrderReference(dealerCode=DC2002, vin=2002, errorBooleanCondition=false)]
10:[OrderReference(dealerCode=PAX1001, vin=1001, errorBooleanCondition=true), OrderReference(dealerCode=PAX1002, vin=1002, errorBooleanCondition=false), OrderReference(dealerCode=PAX1003, vin=1003, errorBooleanCondition=false), OrderReference(dealerCode=DC2001, vin=2001, errorBooleanCondition=true), OrderReference(dealerCode=DC2002, vin=2002, errorBooleanCondition=false)]
```

**Expected output:**

```
20:[ OrderReference(dealerCode=PAX1002, vin=1002, errorBooleanCondition=false), OrderReference(dealerCode=PAX1003, vin=1003, errorBooleanCondition=false), OrderReference(dealerCode=DC2002, vin=2002, errorBooleanCondition=false)]
10:[OrderReference(dealerCode=PAX1001, vin=1001, errorBooleanCondition=true), OrderReference(dealerCode=DC2001, vin=2001, errorBooleanCondition=true)]
```

I'm not getting the expected output and it might be with the object creation of "oderRefErrorList ". I tried to create oderRefErrorList  in the for loop of bulkAmendment but the outcome is not as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have a single `List<OrderStatus`, referred to by variable `oderRefErrorList`, which you use as the value for all entries in integerListFinalMap.

There is only one list. The map stores a reference to the list, not a copy of the list, so all keys have the same list as value.

You need to arrange to have a distinct list for each possible key. Something like this, perhaps: (at each place where you currently have a 'put' into the map)

```
// At this point we've decided that this orderRef
// needs a particular error number, errorNo, and
// we want to update its entry in the 'final map'

List<OrderStatus> list = integerListFinalMap.get(errorNo);
if (list == null) {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    integerListFinalMap.put(errorNo, list);
}
list.add(orderRef);
```

This works like this: when we're about to update the map, we see whether we have an entry for this particular error case. If we do not, then we make a new entry with an empty list. If we do, then we find the existing list. Either way, then we add the orderRef to that list.

There are more succinct ways to write the same thing, but I think this step-by-step approach is the easiest way to understand it for a beginner.